# Read media file's APIC image data in Java

Tags: java, albumart

I am working on my HTTP server, and I am currently implementing the ability to read and display media tags and information of files(such as mp4, m4a, wav, etc.) to clients. So far I have tags such as title, track number, year, album, artist, copyright, etc. working perfectly for multiple file extensions using [JAudioTagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/maven/apidocs/)(binaries available [here](https://bitbucket.org/ijabz/jaudiotagger/downloads), website [here](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/)).

What I am now trying to do is implement the ability to read and convert the image data, or album artwork/cover data, and send that data to clients as png, jpeg, etc. separately. I have visited and read the official section on the APIC tag [here](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#Attached_picture), but I can't figure out how to convert the data or where the data actually starts in the tag.

Here is the code I wrote to retrieve the album artwork data from a file containing it:

```
public static final byte[] readFileArtwork(File file) {
    if(file == null || !file.isFile()) {
        return null;
    }
    AudioFile afile = null;
    try {
        afile = AudioFileIO.read(file);
    } catch(CannotReadException e) {
        System.err.print("Unable to read file: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.print("An I/O Exception occurred: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(TagException e) {
        System.err.print("Unable to read file's tag data: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(ReadOnlyFileException e) {//???
        System.err.print("Unable to read file: File is read only: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(InvalidAudioFrameException e) {
        System.err.print("Unable to read file's audio frame data: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] data = new byte[0];
    if(afile == null) {
        return data;
    }
    Iterator<TagField> tags = afile.getTag().getFields();
    while(tags.hasNext()) {
        TagField tag = tags.next();
        if(tag.isBinary()) {
            if(tag.getId().equals("APIC")) {
                try {
                    data = tag.getRawContent();
                } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    System.err.print("Unable to read file's image data: ");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return data == null ? new byte[0] : data;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you take a look at the [Artwork](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/examples_artwork.jsp) support in JAudioTagger and the Java [ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) class? To get access to the pictures and convert them to PNGs you should be able to do something like:

```
for (Artwork artwork : afile.getTag().getArtworkList()) {
  BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage) artwork.getImage();
  ImageIO.write(bi, "png", outputstream);
}
```

The getPictureType(), getMimeType(), etc. accessors on Artwork can be used to access the other picture metadata described in the ID3 spec.

Comment: Well I'll be, thanks for pointing out the obvious. I'll get right on that then accept your answer!

Comment: Knew I was missing something.

Comment: Yep, I was too focused on trying to read the tag data to poke around the api.